# Integer promotion for implementations where sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

#### Background

I'm looking into integer promotion rules in C++, and came across the following (taken from [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)):

> **4.5.1 [pconv.prom]**
>
> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of `int` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int` if `int` can represent all the values of the source type;
>   otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type
>   `unsigned int`.

> **4.13.1.3 [conv.rank]**
>
> - The rank of `long long int` shall be greater than the rank of `long int`, which shall be greater than the rank of `int`, which
>     shall be greater than the rank of `short int`, which shall be greater
>     than the rank of `signed char`.

> **5.10 [expr]**
>
> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result
>   types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which
>   is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the usual
>   arithmetic conversions , which are defined as follows:
>
> *[many points omitted]*
>
> - Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.
>
> *[further omissions]*

#### Question

Given that both the size and range of `short int` may be equal to that of `int`, it seems unecessary to promote a `short int` to an `int` in those circumstances. Yet, the above makes no mention of such an exception.

Does the standard require that `short int` is promoted to `int` in these circumstances (even if implementation optimisations presult in the same executable being produced)?

#### Note / additional question

I've also noticed that the wording uses "can be" rather than "shall be", is this intentional?

Comment: What makes you think `short int` can have the same size and range as an `int`?

Comment: Maybe this would make more sense if you also looked the rules for when promotions happen?

Comment: @Javia1492 the standard defines it so

Comment: @Hurkyl what section is that in? Thanks :)

Comment: @Javia: Because it can. e.g. `short int` is required to be at least 16 bits, and for a long time, most environments made `int` a 16-bit type. Consequently....

Comment: @OMGtechy: I don't have a copy in front of me, but I imagine there are either relevant words around where you're reading, or you'll have to look at things that talk about stuff that requires promotions (e.g. look up what `+` does)

Comment: @Javia1492 The standard, basically, says that `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)`.

Comment: @Hurkyl ok thanks, I'll do  some more digging :)

Comment: [This reference about implicit conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) also contains a [section on numeric promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Numeric_promotions). Don't know if it tells you more than the specification does though. And even if the promotion have to happen, I think that most compilers today are smart enough to simply not do anything if the sizes are the same.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree about the implementation point, I'm just curious on whether it's supposed to regardless of optimisations. I used your links to find more relevant parts of the standard, thanks!

Comment: @Javia1492: What makes you think it can't? In addition to some systems making `short` and `int` both 16 bits, as others have mentioned, I've worked on systems (Cray vector systems) where they're both 64 bits. Either is perfectly valid.

Comment: If `short` and `int` are the same size, the promotion has zero cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly legitimate, and at one time was extremely commonplace, for `short` and `int` to have identical ranges and representations; even in today it's not uncommon for embedded systems to use the same 16-bit representation for both.  The C specification does contain some language which is specific to such implementations, since on such platforms `unsigned short` promotes to `unsigned int` whereas it promotes to `signed int` on platforms where the latter type can represent all values of `unsigned short`.  It does not exempt such implementations from the rule requiring that types smaller than `int` or `unsigned int` be promoted to one of those because nothing would be gained from such an exemption.

The standard allows that an implementation may perform computations in any fashion it sees fit if, in all cases where the indicated promotions to `int` or `unsigned int` would yield defined behavior, the implementations' computations yield that same behavior (the *as-if* rule).  If the behaviors of rvalues of types `int` and `short` would be indistinguishable, that would imply that an implementation could perform computations on `short` rather than `int` if it chose to do so.  There's no need to add a rule to the standard exempting `int`-sized `short` types from promotion since the as-if rule is already adequate.

Comment: Thanks, the as if part nailed it :)

Comment: @OMGtechy: Until recently, almost all compilers used to honor another as-if rule which has alas never been added to the standard: if the result of an integer `+`, `-`, `*` or bitwise operator is cast or coerced to an unsigned integer type smaller than `int`, the result should be as if the operands were coerced to that smaller type and the operation performed using that type.  In all cases where the Standard prescribes behavior, it requires that compilers behave identically to what the rule would prescribe, but the Standard leaves some cases Undefined.

Comment: Consequently, given `uint16_t x=65533;` the statement `x*=x` will behave identically on all compilers where `int` is either 16 bits, or at least 33 bits, but may negate the laws of time and causality on compilers where `int` is 32 bits.  I don't see any benefit to allowing platforms where `int` is 17 to 32 bits to have different behavior from those where `int` is any other size, but the Standard at present exempts such compilers from the principle that unsigned types should abide by the rules of modular arithmetic.